# Jenkins PHP Unit Test and Code Coverage unable to import in SonarQube

Tags: php, testing, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have been struggling with importing unit test results and code coverage from Jenkins into SonarQube. At this point, I have verified the results are being generated as they are displayed in the project's page in Jenkins.

The sonar.properties file is shown below. The php results were created with phpunit and the code coverage was created with phpunit and clover. As an effort in troubleshooting, I included both sonar.php.coverage.reportPath and sonar.clover.reportPath.

```
sonar.projectKey=projectKey
sonar.projectName=projectKey
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=php
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.php.tests.reportPath=report/phpunitresults.xml
sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=report/clover_code_coverage.xml
sonar.clover.reportPath=report/clover_code_coverage.xml 

sonar.sources=./src/
sonar.exclusions=./src/tests/**
sonar.tests=./src/tests/
sonar.coverage.exclusions=./src/tests/**/*.php
```

All of the results
Unit Tests Coverage
0.0%
Line Coverage
0.0%

The Jenkins builds do not produce any errors or helpful information in identifying a problem as to why the results are not being imported.

Can anyone help in troubleshooting the issue?

Thanks.

- Ben

Comment: which version of php plugin you are using within sonarqube. Also, which sonarqube version you are using.

Comment: in which format you are generating your test reports?

Comment: The version information is: sonarqube is 5.0.1, sonar-runner is 2.4, and the jenkins php plugin is 2.6.

Comment: As for the format, I have been trying multiple types. SonarQube is able to handle the clover format according to its documentation, so that is the version currently applied. I have also tried jUnit format for unit tests and PHP_CodeCoverage for code coverage.

Comment: as per your specification, the versions are fine and it should work.

Comment: I agree that it should work. I have a sample project up which sends the correct information to sonarqube. This is displayed properly. Do you have any suggestions for strategies of troubleshooting?

Comment: yes, i have some suggestions and strategies for troubleshooting. please run sonar analysis on this project link:https://github.com/abhijeetka/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests . if the analysis is going correct and its displaying result them we can see there is an issue with the reports that you are generating with PHPUnit.

Comment: That project has already been added to the build as a sanity check. It runs as expected. Note that I can create clover code coverage reports and phpunit test reports. These are displayed within Jenkins without issue. Based on some of the information in the logs, my assumption is that sonar is unable to find the source code files. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry ben but its really very hard for me to debug this without checking your sonarqube issue. Could you please modify your question and add sonar execution log which comes after running sonar-runner. That will really help me to solve this.

Comment: @ben could you provide the debug log of the analysis and a sample of the xml report  please ? The plugin is supposed to log information when it is not able to find some source file associated to coverage results; which will could explain the 0% coverage you have.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that coverage reports were generated on server different from where `sonar-scanner` was run, and the absolute paths in `clover.xml` differed.

Solution was to fix the paths:

```
replace="s|/home/bamboo/project/|`pwd`/|g"
sed -i -- $replace report/*.xml
```