# How can I make SonarQube PHP plugin work with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, sonarqube

I had install jenkins and SonarQube Runner 2.4 ,SonarQube Server 5.1.2, php plugin 2.6,phpunit5.1
and then i run with standalone sonarqube analysis,this is my configuration:

```
sonar.language=php
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.phpCodesniffer.timeout=120
sonar.projectKey=xxx
sonar.projectName=xxxx
sonar.sources=.
sonar.tests=./tests/tests/
```

Here is the console output:

```
$ /apps/svr/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner -e -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/home/apps/.jenkins/workspace/pc_dev_example -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.language=php -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=php:pc_dev_example -Dsonar.phpUnit.argumentLine="/apps/svr/sonar" -Dsonar.inclusions=applications/vipuser/public/passport.php -Dsonar.phpCodesniffer.timeout=120 -Dsonar.tests=./tests/tests/ -Dsonar.projectName=pc_dev_example
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_71 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /apps/svr/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/apps/.jenkins/workspace/pc_dev_example/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
15:56:42.207 INFO  - Load global repositories
15:56:42.471 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=267ms
15:56:42.474 INFO  - Server id: 20151009151309
15:56:42.477 INFO  - User cache: /home/apps/.sonar/cache
15:56:42.490 INFO  - Install plugins
15:56:42.634 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
15:56:42.642 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
15:56:44.209 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
15:56:45.887 INFO  - Load project repositories
15:56:46.582 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=695ms
15:56:46.582 INFO  - Load project settings
15:56:47.405 INFO  - Load technical debt model
15:56:47.432 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
15:56:47.697 INFO  - -------------  Scan pc_dev_vip_example
15:56:47.702 INFO  - Load module settings
15:56:47.862 INFO  - Language is forced to php
15:56:47.871 INFO  - Load rules
15:56:48.455 INFO  - Base dir: /home/apps/.jenkins/workspace/pc_dev_example
15:56:48.455 INFO  - Working dir: /home/apps/.jenkins/workspace/pc_dev_example/.sonar
15:56:48.456 INFO  - Source paths: .
15:56:48.456 INFO  - Test paths: tests/tests
15:56:48.457 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
15:56:48.457 INFO  - Index files
15:56:48.470 INFO  - Included sources: 
15:56:48.470 INFO  -   applications/vipuser/public/passport.php
15:56:48.542 INFO  - 2 files indexed
15:56:48.542 INFO  - 470 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
15:56:48.610 INFO  - Quality profile for php: Sonar way
15:56:48.736 INFO  - Sensor NoSonar and Commented out LOC Sensor
15:56:48.769 INFO  - Sensor NoSonar and Commented out LOC Sensor (done) | time=33ms
15:56:48.769 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
15:56:48.771 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=2ms
15:56:48.771 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
15:56:48.775 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=4ms
15:56:48.775 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
15:56:48.798 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=23ms
15:56:48.798 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
15:56:48.806 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=8ms
15:56:48.806 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
15:56:48.833 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=27ms
15:56:48.834 INFO  - Sensor PHPSquidSensor
15:56:48.880 INFO  - 1 source files to be analyzed
15:56:49.109 INFO  - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
15:56:49.132 INFO  - Sensor PHPSquidSensor (done) | time=298ms
15:56:49.132 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor
15:56:49.132 INFO  - No PHPUnit test report provided (see 'sonar.php.tests.reportPath' property)
15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit unit test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.reportPath' property)
15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit integration test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.itReportPath' property)
15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit overall coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.overallReportPath' property)
15:56:49.133 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor (done) | time=1ms
15:56:49.133 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
15:56:49.137 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=4ms
15:56:49.137 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
15:56:49.137 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for php
15:56:49.137 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
15:56:49.180 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=43ms
15:56:49.182 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
15:56:49.240 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-09)
15:56:49.249 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-09, analysis of Fri Oct 09 10:02:34 CST 2015)
15:56:49.618 INFO  - Execute decorators...
15:56:50.177 INFO  - Store results in database
15:56:50.494 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 21ms, dir size=1 KB
15:56:50.504 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 10ms, zip size=2 KB
15:56:50.552 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 48ms
15:56:50.552 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://10.199.250.171:9040/dashboard/index/php:pc_dev_vip_example
15:56:50.552 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.930s
Final Memory: 17M/563M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It run success,and I can see the sonar report,but PHPUnit Test is not work,look at this,it seems that it can not find phpunit,but i had install on the server.Any one knows how does this happen?How can i make PHPunit work?

```
15:56:49.132 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor
    15:56:49.132 INFO  - No PHPUnit test report provided (see 'sonar.php.tests.reportPath' property)
    15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit unit test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.reportPath' property)
    15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit integration test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.itReportPath' property)
    15:56:49.133 INFO  - No PHPUnit overall coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.overallReportPath' property)
    15:56:49.133 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor (done) | time=1ms
```

Answer (score 9):

to generate unit and coverage reports for sonar-scanner with phpunit :

you have to install xdebug before

```
pecl install xdebug
```

then

```
php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so phpunit.phar --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-clover phpunit.coverage.xml --log-junit phpunit.report.xml
```

Changes in your `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=phpunit.coverage.xml
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=phpunit.report.xml
```

Comment: `sonar.php.coverage.reportPath` should be `sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths`, missed a `s`. see https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Answer (score 2):

From your logs:

```
No PHPUnit test report provided (see 'sonar.php.tests.reportPath' property)
```

You should configure sonar.php.tests.reportPath as mentioned in the logs and in the documentation on ["PHP Unit Test and Coverage Results Import"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PHP+Unit+Test+and+Coverage+Results+Import).

Comment: It doesn't work as well.When I set the path,it reports:it can not find the file.So It look likes the PHPUnit is not work,and the file can not product.

Comment: Can you please share your setting of sonar.php.tests.reportPath and the reported message?

Comment: yes,My config:sonar.php.tests.reportPath=phpunit.xml,output:Sensor PHPUnit Sensor
17:45:23.818 INFO  - PHPUnit xml test report not found: phpunit.xml
17:45:23.818 INFO  - No PHPUnit unit test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.reportPath' property)
17:45:23.818 INFO  - No PHPUnit integration test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.itReportPath' property)
17:45:23.818 INFO  - No PHPUnit overall coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.overallReportPath' property)
17:45:23.818 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor (done) | time=0ms

Comment: Is the phpunit.xml file at the root of the analysed project? Did it exist when you ran the analysis?

Comment: There is no phpunit.xml file in the project,the file is a report,so it should be producted by PHPUnit,Is it?

Comment: The SonarQube PHP plugin does not execute PHPunit, it imports results from an existing report. You have to generate the report before running the analysis. Please see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PHP+Unit+Test+and+Coverage+Results+Import.

Comment: How can i execute PHPunit,in old version,I have set sonar.tests ,it can run PHPunit ,but in new version,It can not

Comment: You should read the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/documentation.html). This is not related to SonarQube. You should post a new question, not add comments here, if you have doubts about executing PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

As others answered, you need to generate coverage reports from `phpunit` by setting `--coverage-clover`.

One very important point is that it won't work by only setting that parameter and you need to set whitelist directories:

- [Whitelist for phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840022/jenkins-php-unit-test-and-code-coverage-unable-to-import-in-sonarqube?rq=1)
- [Docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `phpunit` (*in Symfony*) with SonarQube
You need to install

- xdebug: `pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`
- tokenizer: `composer require nette/tokenizer`

After you run yours tests and store the report in a file by:

```bash
php bin/phpunit --coverage-clover reports.xml
```

In finish to run Sonar Scanner:

```bash
vendor/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.host.url=repository-sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=akileepay:backend -Dsonar.exclusions=src/Migrations/** -Dsonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=reports.xml
```